# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libreanimated.so" not found React Native Reanimated Issue React Native

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-screens

Hey folks I am facing a critical issue on project while running the app on Android. I have visited the related question but not found any solution. Error is following.

```
complete error:  Error: Exception in HostFunction: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libreanimated.so" not found
```

```
react-native version: 0.67.3
react-native-reanimated: 2.10.0
```

`classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0")`

```
minSdkVersion = 21
compileSdkVersion = 31
targetSdkVersion = 31
```

> This error is showing when I install the react-native-reanimated
> package if I remove this package then this error is removed but I need
> this package because my drawer navigation depend on this pacakge

If anyone face this issue and resolved it completely Please guide me the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue although with more recent packages.

I found a fix here: https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/5625

React Native 0.73 comes by default with ndk = 25.1.8937393.
To fix it, I had to drop the NDK to 23.1.7779620

UPDATE:
Using NDK 26 fixes this altogether, probably a better option if upgrading is not too much hassle for you.

Go to Android Studio->Tools->SDK Manager->SDK tools->Install latest version of NDK (v26)

Then run:

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install 
npm start -- --reset-cache
'a'
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but I struggled a bit with this error.

Make sure the following:

on `app/build.gradle` right above this line: `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` add:

```
project.ext.react = [
        enableHermes: true,
        bundleInDebug: true <--- make sure this is set to true
]

// also add this to force rebuild reanimated:
project.ext.reanimated = [
        buildFromSource: true
]
```

Answer (score -1):

I have been facing this issue since 2 Dec 2022. Please add the following line in your `build.gradle` (app) in side Android.

```
packagingOptions 
{   
 pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libreanimated.so' <=== this one
}
```

Comment: the libreanimated.so file is not being included in the APK. How can this resolve the issue? This would solve if multiple .so files with the same name were found